# Uncaught Error FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### here show: var cod = document.getElementById("codigo").value;------------- I get an error when I want to pass the cod variable of the document.getElementById -- doc(cod); show error.-- How do I make the query in firestore?

```
Uncaught Error FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.
    at Br (d:\Documentos\app web 2\firebasejs\firestore\dist\prebuilt.js:184:9)
    at Xd (d:\Documentos\app web 2\firebasejs\firestore\dist\prebuilt.js:14495:19)
    at gp (d:\Documentos\app web 2\firebasejs\firestore\dist\prebuilt.js:14886:44)
    at im.doc (d:\Documentos\app web 2\firebasejs\firestore\dist\prebuilt.js:18010:79)
    at mostrarFila (d:\Documentos\app web 2\ventas1\ventas1.js:24:44)
    at onclick (d:\Documentos\app web 2\ventas1\ventas1.html:49:105)
Br @ d:\Documentos\app web 2\firebasejs\firestore\dist\prebuilt.js:184:9
```

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

var cod = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
//para que me muestre la tabla del tbody todas las filas con sus columanas
var tabla =document.getElementById("tabla");

function mostrarFila(){
    var docRef = db.collection("Producto").doc(cod);/* aca está el error*/

tabla.innerHTML= "";

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data().codigo);

    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
}
```

Comment: When is the `mostrarFila` function called ? Looking at this, you're getting the value of `#codigo` at the get go (when it is probably empty) not when it is actually used.

Comment: I already put it inside the get.Element.By.Id function but the firebase statement does not take the cod variable

Comment: The problem is that `cod` will be the value of the `#codingo` input when `document.getElementById("codigo").value` was called (`cod` doesn't update when you add something to the input). Try to move `var cod = document.getElementById("codigo").value;` inside the `mostrarFila` and you'll probably get the expected result.

Comment: It's what I told you I did, but it doesn't read it, it says document not found, it can't find the document

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally works, you were right, I had to wait a long time for the code update to take me, thank you very much